# How to show that $R$ is an equivalence relation？

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For all $p, q, m, n\in N$, we define $R$ as follows:$$(p,q)R(m,n)\Leftrightarrow pn=qm$$

Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $N$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: It should be $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$

Comment: The claim in the title is false.

Answer (score 2):

$R$ is not an equivalence relation because $(1,1)R(0,0)$ and $(0,0)R(2,1)$ and $\neg ((1,1)R(2,1))$.

Comment: $(0,0)$ doesn't belong to $N\times N$

Comment: @NitinUniyal That’s dependent on your definition of $\mathbb N$. Really, this should’ve been clarified by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

View the pair $(p,q)$ as a fraction $\frac{p}{q}$. Proving $R$ is reflexive and symmetric are clear. What does transitivity mean in this new interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

$(p,q)R(p,q)$ holds as $pq=qp$ so $R$ is reflexive.

$(p,q)R(m,n)\implies pn=qm\implies mq=np\implies (m,n)R(p,q)$ so $R$ is symmetric.

$(p,q)R(m,n)$ and $(m,n)R(r,s)\implies pn=qm$ & $ms=nr$

On multiplication, this gives $pnms=qmnr\implies ps=qr$ on cancellation. This implies $(p,q)R(r,s)$ so $R$ is transitive.

**Addendum**- I assumed that the set of natural numbers $N$ doesn't include $0$.